# How can i access the file-selection in Path Finder via py-appscript?

Tags: python, macos, applescript, path-finding, sourceforge-appscript

Using the filemanager Path Finder on mac os x, i wanna retrieve the selected files/folders with python by using [py-appscript](http://appscript.sourceforge.net). py-appscript is a high-level event bridge that allows you to control scriptable Mac OS X applications from Python.

In applescript it would be something like

```
tell application "Path Finder"
 set selection_list to selection -- list of fsItems (fsFiles and fsFolders)
 set _path to posix path of first item of selection_list
 do shell script "python " & quoted form of _path
end tell
```

In python it would instead something like

```
from appscript import *
selectection_list = app('Path Finder').selection.get()   # returns reference, not string
```

So, how can i convert the references in selection_list to python-strings?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Pathfinder, but if it has its own file URL type (or maybe it's a POSIX path?), then there is presumably a delimiter of some kind that separates the levels of file hierarchy in the path. To convert between one and the other, you need to work with `Applescript's text item delimiters`. Something along these lines should work

```
set thePathFinderPath to "/pathfinder/path/to/finder"

set pathFinderPathDelimiter to "/" -- whatever it may be here
set finderPathDelimiter to ":"

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {pathFinderPathDelimiter}
set thePathComponents to (get every text item in thePathFinderPath) as list
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {finderPathDelimiter}
set theFinderPath to thePathComponents as text
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "" -- very important you clear the TIDs.
```

Add salt to taste. But, if you can provide an example of the PathFinder URL, then I can provide a better answer.

Comment: I'm searching for python-code, not applescript. Sorry if my question were misleading, i've correct her now,

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try python-applescript, it can run applescript's script thru python. Get it here : http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-applescript